# What is bluez "bluetoothctl scan on" (StartDiscovery) doing that "hcitool lescan" is not

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I see its adding a file to /var/lib/bluetooth/hci MAC/cache/ for each discovered device with its name as the address.  Documentation says its creating device objects.  Where and what are they, virtual dbus objects? ( ex: /dev_F8:41:1B:6B:95:2A). I know the device is removed after 3 minutes if not connected.  And what else is it doing to make a device available for connecting with the bluez dbus interface.  Thanks.

Comment: The BlueZ DBus API is documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc. There are examples of how to use it at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test

Answer (score 0):

Bluetoothctl uses the Bluez DBus apis to do everything it does. When you do 'scan on' in bluetoothctl, it will call the StartDiscovery method of the Adapter object. Internally the Dbus will use the HCI interface to start a lescan. Once advertisement come in, Bluez will create objects for them on the Dbus and will send an InterfaceAdded or PropertiesChanged signals on the Dbus. Your application can listen to those signals which contain the address of the objects they are about.